# Modified non-abelian Wilson loop

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, lie-algebra, wilson-loop

Consider a $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ Wilson loop in some representation $R$,
$$W_R= \mathrm{Tr}_R\left\{\mathcal P\exp\left(i \oint \mathrm dx^{\mu} A^a_{\mu} T^a\right)\right\}$$
where $T^a= \sigma^a/2$ is the generator of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ Lie algebra, and $A^a$ is the connection with $a=1,2,3$ and $\mathcal P$ is the path ordering operator. One can further define a modified Wilson loop

$$\tilde W_R^b= \mathrm{Tr}_R\left\{T^b\ \mathcal P\exp\left(i \oint \mathrm dx^{\mu} A^a_{\mu} T^a\right)\right\}$$
where we insert a Lie algebra generator $T^b$ before taking the trace.

The question is: Is $W_{R}^{-1} \tilde{W}_R^b$ independent of the connection $A^a$, and is only a group theoretical factor? If so, is there a simple expression for this group theoretical factor?

Comment: Crossposted in [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268173/modified-nonabelian-wilson-line)

Comment: Hint: It will depend on the connection $A^a$. Try make a perturbative expansion.

Comment: $e^{i A^a T^a}$ is an element of the gauge group whereas $T^a$ is an element of the algebra. Is it clear that $T^a  e^{i A^a T^a}$ is even well-defined?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no, the expectation value of a generator w.r.t. a group element as a measure (and so in the [Universal enveloping algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra), not the Lie algebra) *does depend*, in general, on the group element parameters, in  your case the gauge fields.

You talk about general representations *R*, but you instantly restrict to the doublet representation. The point is general, but let's stick to the Pauli matrices you restricted to, since the generic group element in the doublet rep is [trivial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector),
$$
~~e^{i \theta \left(\hat{n} \cdot \vec{\sigma}\right)/2} = I\cos{\theta/2} + i (\hat{n} \cdot \vec{\sigma}) \sin{\theta/2} ~.
$$

The Wilson line around a plaquette is thus an SU(2) group element just like this, here a 2×2 matrix, where the three (θ, $\hat n$) group element parameters depend on the gauge fields of the four link/sides of the plaquette. Presumably, you have worked them out as in Schwartz (25.127), or Peskin & Schroeder (15.62-66); there would be no meaning in your otherwise asking.

The trace of this Wilson line is then the Wilson loop,
$$
W= 2 \cos (\theta/2),
$$
while your  quirky expectation value,
$$
\frac{1}{2W}\operatorname{Tr} \sigma^b (I\cos{\theta/2} + i (\hat{n} \cdot \vec{\sigma}) \sin{\theta/2} )=i n^b \tan (\theta/2) .   
$$
So, in general, it depends on the gauge fields through both $n^b$ and $\theta$,
and the statement carries over to all representations, in general. For SU(2) there are closed formulas for all representations, analogous to the above for the doublet, but it's not worth going [there](https://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/2014/084/).